# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \Big[ \exp \Big(\log^\beta(x) - \log^\beta \big(x + y \big(\frac{x}{\beta \log^{\beta-1}(x)} \big) ) \Big) \Big]$

Tags: limits

I am trying to prove that

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \Big[ \exp \Big(\log^\beta(x) - \log^\beta \big(x + y \big(\frac{x}{\beta \log^{\beta-1}(x)} \big) ) \Big) \Big] = \exp(-y)$ for $\beta>1$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$,

but I am finding this problem rather difficult. My initial thought was to write it as a fraction and use L'Hopitals 0/0-rule but derivatives of the exponential function aren't really nice to work with. Any ideas to what might work here?

Comment: The variable of $\log^{\beta-1}$ is missing.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\log(\ldots)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\log^\beta x-\log^\beta\left(x+\frac{xy}{\beta\log^{\beta-1}x}\right)\right]
\\\color{LightGray}{[\log(x\Xi)=\log x+\log\Xi]}\quad&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\log^\beta x-\left\{\log x+\log\left(1+\frac{y}{\beta\log^{\beta-1}x}\right)\right\}^\beta\right]
\\\color{LightGray}{[\text{take }\log^\beta x\text{ out}]}\quad&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log^\beta x\left[1-\left\{1+\frac1{\log x}\log\left(1+\frac{y}{\beta\log^{\beta-1}x}\right)\right\}^\beta\right]
\\\color{LightGray}{[\log(1+\delta)=\delta+o(\delta)]}\quad&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log^\beta x\left[1-\left\{1+\frac1{\log x}\frac{y}{\beta\log^{\beta-1}x}\big(1+o(1)\big)\right\}^\beta\right]
\\\color{LightGray}{[(1+\delta)^\beta=1+\beta\delta+o(\delta)]}\quad&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log^\beta x\left[1-\left\{1+\frac{y}{\log^\beta x}+o\left(\frac{1}{\log^\beta x}\right)\right\}\right]
\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\big(-y+o(1)\big)=-y.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice solution ... except that you type too fast for the ooold man !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I'm real quick in **copy & paste** & edit ;) (Thanks!)

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you! Could you maybe explain the second last step a bit more? I'm not sure if I understand it correctly

Comment: @Tranick: (Edited.)